# Intellij Maven [Cannot resolve dependency]

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, nexus

I set up Nexus on my server (api.lielamar.com) and uploaded my first project called PacketManager.
You can view it here: https://api.lielamar.com/#browse/browse:maven-public

For some reason, when I try to import it through pom.xml it just doesn't work. I am fairly new to Maven and extremely new to Nexus so it might be a newbie question.
I tried using google and couldn't find a direct answer that worked for me.

There's my code:

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>lielamar-repo</id>
        <url>https://api.lielamar.com/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lielamar.packetmanager</groupId>
        <artifactId>PacketManager</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am also using the spigot repository which is working just fine.
[This is what I see on the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUEiW.png)

Thank you for your time!

Edit:
One of the problems were that I had my dependency calling a different repo when running mvn install or trying to compile through intellij.
After adding the following code to setting.xml, I started getting a different error:

```
    <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>lielamar-mirror</id>
        <name>lielamar mirror</name>
        <url>https://api.lielamar.com/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-public/</url>
        <mirrorOf>lielamar-api</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

The error I was getting after adding the above code was:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project TestPlugin:
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.lielamar.testplugin:TestPlugin:jar:1.0:
Failure to find com.lielamar.packetmanager:PacketManager:jar:1.0 in
https://api.lielamar.com/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-public/ was cached in the local repository,
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of lielamar-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`
```

I run the command `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` from the cmd and it was built successfully, however, intellij still gives me an error: https://prnt.sc/unxppz

Comment: what does it say when you build it with maven? does it even attempt to download the resources? please append the maven error to your question..

Comment: https://prnt.sc/unwhfc - this is the error when I run mvn install.
I don't know why it tried to access the dependency through a different repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JAR files in the Nexus end with `..jar`, so you probably made a mistake when uploading them (two dots instead of one).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this fast.
I didn't notice the second "." and fixed it, however, it's still happening.
I tried using the link Nexus provides (https://api.lielamar.com/repository/maven-public/) and the direct one (https://api.lielamar.com/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-releases/) but neither worked.
Here's what happens: https://prnt.sc/unufx0

Comment: So, with the first url, did you try a build like `mvn clean verify`? What errors do you get if you run the build?

Comment: This is the error I get:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project TestPlugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.lielamar.testplugin:TestPlugin:jar:1.0: Failure to find com.lielamar.packetmanager:PacketManager:jar:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

no idea why =[

Comment: Do you have a `settings.xml`? If so, does it contain a `<mirror>` entry?

Comment: I added it right now.
Even after adding a settings.xml, a <mirrors> tag and a <mirror> tag inside of it with all of the info, I still get an error.
For some reason maven tries to get my dependency from the central repo.

Here's my settings.xml: https://prnt.sc/unxhre

Comment: I cannot see your `settings.xml`. Note that a mirror might override your repository definition.

Comment: To be honest I already figured things out. A new project was able to import the dependency. I have no idea what went wrong.
Anyways, when packaging my project to create a jar, the final jar doesn't include my dependencies even though I specified them to be compiled with <scope>compile</scope>.
I don't want to bother you anymore but if you know any way of fixing it I would love to hear :P

Comment: jars don't include dependencies unless you explicitly add them by using the maven assembly plugin or the maven shade plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
<snapshotRepository>
<repository>
<id>you-repository-name</id>
<url>http://you-repository-url</url>
</repository>
<snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/unvy1t I get an error saying you can't use repository under snapshotRepository.
I will give it a google search though!:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok to me. Have you checked the [docs](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/maven-repositories?_ga=2.153895743.608786906.1601052620-531769604.1601052620#MavenRepositories-MavenRepositoryFormat)? Perhaps you need to set up Maven first. To make sure it is a Maven issue, also try running your Maven build from outside of Intellij -- just a common practice, as I doubt it is the case that Intellij has anything to do with it.

Comment: I have read the docs already but since it's my real first encounter with maven things were a bit too complicated there.
I will re-read it though!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your repository url by `https://api.lielamar.com/repository/maven-releases/`
The one you have points to a group, if you check on nexus.
The group one might need to be referenced in a different way if they can be referenced at all.

or you might need something like this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#group-level-maven-endpoint

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/GROUP_ID/-/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/packages/maven</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: That's correct. The first URL points at a group, however, I did try to reference each of the group members individually and nothing worked. I will try out your second suggestion. It looks promising ^^